# If humans had evolved with "natural forcefields", would blunt-trauma weapons replace spears as dominant battlefield weapons?

Tags: internal-consistency, warfare, weapons, military

EDIT: I now realize that asking for a logical extrapolation from the consequences of auras upon ancient, post-classical, and modern warfare was far too broad considering warfare in these periods vastly differed in terms of tactics and military technologies developed in those contexts. For that reason, I attempted to narrow down the extrapolation to early ancient/prehistoric warfare only, not including weapons technology of the time. Hopefully, this is a more focused question.

EDIT 2: I've taken some time to think about how to narrow the question down such that it asks a specific, focused question. I'm particularly interested in the types of weapons that would have been developed in a world where early humans possessed what amounts to be natural, sturdy body armor, so I narrowed the question down to whether blunt weapons would have become far more common than spears, which have been historically the primary battlefield weapon for most of human history.

## Preface

I'm designing a homebrew setting for a campaign based in an alternate version of the [RWBY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RWBY) canon. This version significantly differs from canon on many events, mechanics, and other lore elements whose specifics are not completely relevant to this question, but the overall trajectory remains somewhat similar to canon: this AU takes place in the pre-cataclysmic times of humanity before the Twins (who are essentially the Brother Gods in canon) punished them by sending humanity back to Stone-age hunter-gatherer societies via a cataclysmic event. The Creatures of Grimm are part of this divine punishment and so do not appear up until the fall of humanity, so for all intents and purposes assume the Grimm do not exist anywhere in precursor human history.

As of this writing, the campaign could theoretically take place in any period in precursor human history up to the fall (I haven't decided which period to set the campaign itself in yet). The periods themselves matter little, as this question will be focused on the ancient era of precursor history.

Auras are integral in this question (and their rules, rewritten from the canon, will be outlined below), but the rules behind semblances are still being worked out and might become integral in a future question down the road. To keep things more simple, assume semblances do not exist.

#### Question

Let's suppose that precursor humanity, thanks to the cooperation between the Twins/Brother Gods, evolved on Remnant with a specific set of genes. These genes are subject to the same evolutionary pressures as any other gene and they are the reason humans have auras. Auras work somewhat similarly to their canon counterparts with six key differences:

1. Auras are "invisible" fields produced by breathing. A more scientific explanation would be that these fields are composed of trillions of special subatomic particles that are generated by cellular respiration. These particles tend to orbit around the atoms of human cells and can respond to their parent cells' electrical and chemical signals; after a set period of time, say roughly one hour, and assuming they are not utilized by the aura field, the particles are naturally recycled back into a human cell and converted into ATP.

   - More specifically, aura particles are created from ATP. During cellular respiration, after ATP is produced, the human cell sets aside some of its ATP and, through biological processes thanks to its aura genes, converts it into aura particles.
   - ATP recycled back from aura particles *can* be reconverted into an aura particle again. As a result, the aura field is constantly recycling and regenerating its field every hour, every day, for the entire life of its owner.
2. Auras hold two auxiliary properties: they can accelerate the healing of bodily wounds(1) and they can enhance human strength to a great degree(2). When performing these functions, the aura particles involved get converted into ATP and are normally used in cellular processes relevant to healing and exertion of strength.

   - (1): Someone with a broken arm, assuming proper physical therapy, can heal their injury in three-fourths the time it would normally take.
   - (2): An untrained male human of average strength and weight with aura can lift objects of their body weight with relative ease; an untrained female human of average strength and weight with aura can lift objects the untrained male human can lift without aura also with relative ease.
3. Auras are normally inert. However, they are intertwined with a person's fight-or-flight response and therefore can be activated into a field in a span of milliseconds if a person feels threatened. A person can also voluntarily will their aura into action.

   - Acceleration of healing is an involuntary response; an aura, inert or otherwise, will always assist in the healing process.
4. Auras primarily protect their host by acting as an ablative shield―that is, deflecting harmful forces away from their host's body. When met with a sudden impact, particles immediately concentrate around the impact site and absorb the incoming force, carrying it away from the person by breaking off from the aura field. When not voluntarily activated, auras naturally trigger when an incoming force starts causing physical trauma upon the host's body (e.g: a person getting punched in the chest by another person).

   - Auras can apply this concept against extremely hot things like fire, where the particles can absorb the incoming heat and carry it away from the person, breaking off as a result.

     - It can similarly act against harmfully-cold things, wherein the particles instead transfer its heat into the incoming cold and again breaking off, keeping its host’s body relatively warm.
   - Auras can also act against harmful chemicals and gases like acid that harm the host's body upon contact. However, they are unable to act against any harmful chemical/noxious gas that get ingested/absorbed into the human body itself. Although, they can still heal any harmed tissues and organs to a degree and can even prolong the life of the affected person to a degree assuming no medical attention is received.
5. As auras are generated by cellular respiration and still subjected to homeostasis, there is an upper limit to the aura's protective properties. A person will eventually tire out if their aura continues to deflect physical harm away from their body and/or exert muscular strength for a prolonged period. Eventually, the person will suffer physical exhaustion and their aura will actually become inert again, leaving the person vulnerable to harm until they recover from exhaustion.

   - The time it takes to deplete a person's aura is dependent upon the person's physical training and the severity of the attack. An average untrained person is able to at least withstand two direct hits from a large club before the third hit breaks their aura and hurts them; an elite soldier can withstand a direct blow equivalent to a couched lance from a 15th century knight on horseback at full speed *and* still have usable aura left over.
   - Should the aura become forcibly inert, their auxiliary properties also cease to function until their host recovers from physical exhaustion.
6. Auras can not only be improved through exercise, they can also be voluntarily manipulated with sufficient training. Generally-speaking, a person with a physically-active lifestyle can produce far more aura particles than another person who lives a sedentary lifestyle. It takes only a few days to train someone to extend their aura out beyond the boundaries of their physical bodies, allowing them to also encapsulate and protect external objects at the cost of energy if they are not physically fit.

   - The ability to extend one's aura to protect external objects is considered a basic ability in this version of Remnant.

With these differences in mind, suppose precursor humanity develops civilization in a somewhat similar trajectory to our own prehistoric and early ancient history, with various cultures founding settlements that eventually grow into city-states, kingdoms, and perhaps even empires. Doubtless, these cultures would have waged war with at least one other in this hypothetical history. Assuming similar technological and sociocultural development, would the soldiers of their respective cultures still wield spears, or would the arms race instead lean towards weapons that deal maximum blunt-force impact upon their target?

Comment: Yes. But more importantly, aura has far stronger effects when it comes to economics and medicine. People with aura can't get sick easily and since the aura acts as a healing factor, they also get better faster and/or don't die. Not to mention that the increase in a single person's production capacity with the assistance of aura means that the amount of goods and services in the world would be drastically improved.

Comment: As it stands this is far too broad.

Comment: Getting there... You're still asking [***too many questions***](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post). You are very welcome, and indeed encouraged, to ask multiple queries about the same worldbuilding problem. Also, asking a query like "what ways can" is too broad & needs to be focused. Pick one way and ask about that; perhaps extrapolate from that to some of the other ways you're wondering about.